# Should I perform equations in my queries, or perform them locally and update the db

Tags: mysql, database

I am building a site with a **Posts** and a **Votes** table. Each vote points to a post and is either up or down

If I am wanting to sort the posts with a complex equation like this

```
def hotness(ups, downs, date):
    s = ups - downs
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(sign * order + seconds / 45000, 7)
```

Would it be better to:

1. Translate that equation to sql, perform a join with the votes, and perform the equation each time I want to fetch and sort a list of posts.
2. Create a hotness column on each post, and update that each time a vote is cast on a post.

The problem I can see with option 1 is that it would add time/complexity to each query, and the problem I could see with option 2 is that there could be 1000's of votes a second meaning the post would need to constantly be updated.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's more important: fast updates, or fast lookups?  If you want the former, go with option 1; if you want the latter, go with option 2.  Benchmark both approaches and see whether the resulting performance is tolerable.

Incidentally, with option 2 one can maintain the `hotness` column with a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE UPDATE ON posts FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.hotness = ROUND(
    SIGN(ups-downs) * LOG10(GREATEST(ABS(ups-downs), 1))
  + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.date) - 1134028003) / 45000
, 7);
```

Then one need merely do `UPDATE posts SET ups = ups + 1 WHERE id = ?` or whatever and `hotness` will automatically be updated.

If neither solution produces acceptable results, you should consider the extent to which you can tradeoff a "live" `hotness` value for one that is cached and updated only periodically.  For example, rather than updating `hotness` in a trigger/on each vote, [schedule an event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/event-scheduler.html) to perform batch updates once every so often.